# Provider and consumer issue

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am fairly new to flutter and I'm trying to level up my state management skills with the provider package. I am facing some difficulties with loading my categories and notifying the listeners when to show my categories widget instead of my modalprogressHUD

here is MyApp class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginProvider>(
          create: (_) => LoginProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CatergoryProvider>(
          create: (_) => CatergoryProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<RegistrationProvider>(
          create: (_) => RegistrationProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<QuestionProvider>(
          create: (_) => QuestionProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
        initialRoute: DashBoard.id,
        routes: {
          WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
          DashBoard.id: (context) => DashBoard(),
          QuizzPage.id: (context) => QuizzPage()
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my CatergoryProvider class:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:quizz_app/models/catergory.dart';
import 'package:quizz_app/services/services.dart';

class CatergoryProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Catergory> catergory;
  String errorMessage;
  bool loading = false;

  Future<bool> fetchCatergory() async {
    setLoading(true);

    await Service(url: "https://quizapp1234.herokuapp.com/kategori")
        .fetchCatergory()
        .then((data) {
      if (data.statusCode == 200) {
        print('success');
        Iterable l = json.decode(data.body);
        setCatergory(
            List<Catergory>.from(l.map((data) => Catergory.fromJson(data))));
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        Map<String, dynamic> result = json.decode(data.body);
        setMessage(result['message']);
      }
    });
    return isList();
  }

  bool isLoading() {
    return loading;
  }

  void setLoading(value) {
    loading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCatergory(value) {
    catergory = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setMessage(value) {
    errorMessage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<Catergory> getList() {
    return catergory;
  }

  String getMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
  }

  bool isList() {
    return catergory != null ? true : false;
  }
}
```

here is where I wrap what I want to be notified with a consumer:

```
  Consumer<CatergoryProvider>(
    builder: (context, catergory, child) {
      catergory.fetchCatergory();
      catergories = catergory.getList();
      return catergory.isLoading()
          ? ModalProgressHUD(
              opacity: 0,
              inAsyncCall:
                  Provider.of<CatergoryProvider>(context).isLoading(),
              child: Scaffold())
          : catergoryPage(catergories, context);
    },
  ),
```

my debug console:

```
════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

the Exception that occurred:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (A CatergoryProvider was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a CatergoryProvider, it can no longer be used.)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On you Consumer inside `builder:` you call `fetchCatergory`, inside `fetchCatergory` method call functions that call `notifyListeners()`, every time that `notifyListeners()` is called, the `builder:` is recalled, causing an infinite loop

Try wrap `catergory.fetchCatergory()` only if `getList()` returns null and `isLoading()` is false

Code:

```
Consumer<CatergoryProvider>(     
    builder: (context, catergory, child) {
        if(!catergory.isLoading() && catergory.getList() == null) {      
            catergory.fetchCatergory();
        }
        catergories = catergory.getList();
        return catergory.isLoading()
            ? ModalProgressHUD(
            opacity: 0,
        inAsyncCall:
            Provider.of<CatergoryProvider>(context).isLoading(),
            child: Scaffold())
        : 
        catergoryPage(catergories, context);
   },
),
```

Comment: works thank you, how ever I recieved another exception called by the library. whic has to do with setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. It was caught in the setLoading method in the catergoryprovider class also says the offending call was made in the consumer<Catergory peovider>

Comment: I had similar issue , your comment helped me to save a lot of time ,thanks